# Checking version of package without installing

Tags: java, dpkg, default-programs

I am undecided about whether to install the default-jdk java
development package or the tarball from sun. How do I check
the version information in the default-jdk or other package
without actually installing it and all its dependencies?

Thanks,

John Goche

Answer (score 1):

run `apt-get install package --print-uris`

this will display all the dependencies of the package you need to install

it will show the package name like below from which you can get the version
`default-jdk_1%3a1.6-42ubuntu2_i386.deb`